# Show a modal popup in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, modal-dialog

My requirement is to show a table using jquery datatable and also popup a modal window on rowclick of the table.
Data is showing in a table and also row values are coming while clicking on the particular row.
Now i need to show a modal popup window which will contain row data and checkboxes will come on the basis of the count of the data.

How can i do this?

For your reference i have created a JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/znqn1kfd/

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' class="glbBtnN" value="View Users" id="btnView" />
    <table id="tblUserDetials" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="display responsive nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Menu Code</th>
                <th>Page Name</th>
                <th>Main Menu</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="divPopUp"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var result = [{ "MenuCode": "UTHRR001", "PageName": "XYZ", "MainMenu": null }, 
              { "MenuCode": "UTHRR002", "PageName": "ABC", "MainMenu": "UTHRR001"}]               

$("#btnView").on('click', function () {
   $('#tblUserDetials').DataTable({
           "aaData":result,
            "columns": [{ "data": "MenuCode" }, { "data": "PageName" }, { "data": "MainMenu" }]
        });
        $(document).on("click", "tbody tr[role='row']", function () {
            alert($(this).closest('tbody tr').children('td:eq(0)').text() + ',' + $(this).closest('tbody tr').children('td:eq(1)').text())
        });
    });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/znqn1kfd/

Comment: Simply add `$(".className").modal()` inside on click method to show modal pop up

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question.

Comment: i have added modal like you said Mr. Ghanshyam. it's not working.